# How to run a longlife background process, linux server

Tags: php, linux, process, background

I am running a webapp (php) that needs to process some "heavy-work" tasks (from 30 sec to 3 min). I know it is not extremely heavy, but I cannot have my user waiting for them, so I've set up an internal API like: `http://localhost/process-picture/745884/` and I store this operation in a MySQL table.

Now I want to create a "process" that fetches that MySQL table and performs the oldest queued operation, and once it is done, it get the next, and so on.

First of all I thought about making a PHP Script that calls by cURL the system like that:

`fetchOperation.php` connects to DB and gets the URL to the operation to call it by cURL.
Every operation: performs itself, and after that deletes itself from the queue and calls (cURL) `fetchOperation.php` again.

I feel that this system is kinda tricky, so I was wondering if there is (and in which language to write it) any way to set up a background process that checks the DB every 15 sec, and does the following:

- Delete all rows marked as `DONE`.
- Check if there is any row marked as `PROCESSING`, if so, just exit and wait for the next 15 sec.
- If there's no `PROCESSING` row, fire the oldest `PENDING` one (FIFO queue).

This way I can manage what is being processed at any time, and even control the server load (for instance, at night allow to have up to three `PROCESSING` items).

Sorry for such a long explanation, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Submit to a queue, and have a crontab that parses the queue for work.

Comment: Is this process must run on the server w/o webserver calls ( such as cron scripts ) ?

Comment: Rows "marked as" means that there is a column containing this info?. Can you write and run scripts in the server where this is happening?

Comment: quinestor, yes the table is as simple as: id_operation, url, status ... status contain the previous values.
By the way, I am using an amazon ec2, so I can run as root, with scripts, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it that way:

1st. Design the operations in a way that they are url callable. For instance: `http://localhost/render-image/14523665`

2nd. Store pending operations in a table like this: operations(opertation-id, operation-url, operation-status).

Once this was ready I designed a short PHP script that does the following:

```
<?php
if( WORKER_IS_ONLINE !== true ) exit();
OperationsQueue::CleanQueue();
while( OperationsQueue::RunningOperations() < WORKER_MAX_OPERATIONS ) {
    launch_operation( OperationsQueue::DequeOperation() );
}
sleep( WORKER_SLEEP_TIME );
launch_operation( '/operations_queue/deque' );
```

This auxiliar functions (`launch_operation` and the `OperationsQueue` class) do as follows (notice it's not yet implemented):

```
<?php 
define('WORKER_SLEEP_TIME', 15);     // Time to sleep between sweeps.
define('WORKER_HOST', 'localhost');  // Hostname where the operations will be performed.
define('WORKER_PORT', 80);       // Port where the operations will be performed.
define('WORKER_SOCKET_TIMEOUT', 80); // Port where the operations will be performed.
define('WORKER_MAX_OPERATIONS', 2);  // Max simultaneous operations.
define('WORKER_MAX_LAUNCHES', 2);    // Max operations launched within a sweep.
define('WORKER_IS_ONLINE', false);   // Bool value that marks whether the worker must be working or not.

function launch_operation($operation) {
    $fp = fsockopen(WORKER_HOST, WORKER_PORT, $errno, $errstr, WORKER_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
    if ($fp) {
        $out  = 'GET ' . $operation . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= 'Host: ' . WORKER_HOST . "\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}

class OperationsQueue {

    public static function RunningOperations(){
        // connect to DB an perform: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM operations WHERE status = 'PROCESSING';
        return 1;
    }
    public static function CleanQueue(){
        // connect to DB an perform: DELETE FROM operations WHERE status IN ('DONE', 'CANCELED');
    }
    public static function DequeOperation(){
        // connect to DB an perform: SELECT * FROM operations WHERE status = 'PENDING' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 1;
        // UPDATE operations SET status = 'PROCESSING', tries = tries+1 WHERE id = $id;
        return 'operation_url';
    }

}
```

**I thought it could be useful to some other people**. As you see it chains the operations.

Comment: If your cron script is php and in that you are calling a php script via a url why not move all php for this functionality into the cron script, you'll then get rid of the unnecessary  network traffic (small though it may be).

Comment: While doing it I got to the point that it may need to run in N secs basis, where cron runs in N minutes intervals. This pointed me to this design. At the same time it allowed me to run it in systems where you don't have shell control, and otherwise you couldn't do it. I am polishing the system, and I may release it at github soon.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need to schedule a job with [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). cron will just run a script/program, so the implementation of that will be distinct from the scheduling itself.

Cron will just fire/forget, so you can invoke processes of any duration from it (I'm looking at your execution time comment below - please amend if I've misunderstood)

Comment: Agree. Maybe additional tweak for php execution time will require

Comment: The `php.ini` used be the CLI-interpreter has noch execution time limit by default, but yes: it cannot hurt to have a look `$ php -i | grep -i max_execution_time`

Comment: Yep this could be a good way. So I just set a cron php that connects to the DB and fires (via cURL requests) what I want. Right?